# Error when trying to build transfer.sh

Tags: go

I am trying to deploy a local instance of [transfer.sh](https://github.com/dutchcoders/transfer.sh).

However, when I run:

```
go run transfersh-server/*.go -provider=local --port 8080 --temp=/tmp/ --basedir=/tmp/
```

I get:

```
transfersh-server/virustotal.go:30:2: cannot find package "github.com/dutchcoders/go-virustotal" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/dutchcoders/go-virustotal (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/share/go/src/github.com/dutchcoders/go-virustotal (from $GOPATH)
transfersh-server/handlers.go:56:2: cannot find package "github.com/russross/blackfriday" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/russross/blackfriday (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/share/go/src/github.com/russross/blackfriday (from $GOPATH)
root@mmv:/home/mihai/transfer.sh# echo $GOROOT
```

The `$GOPATH` is:

```
/usr/share/go
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `go get github.com/dutchcoders/go-virustotal` it should download that package for you